# Is there Developer Documentation for Scandit SDK?

Tags: documentation, barcode-scanner, ipad-2

I am trying to evaluate the Scandit barcode scanner SDK for an iPad2 application.  So far, I have registered for a Developer's license and I think I imported the license file and App key correctly, but still fails to authenticate the demo application.  If I had the documentation it is likely that I can fix this and continue with the evaluation.  Also, the SDK license does not provide any support (forum, telephone, email, etc.).

Comment: Since I posted this, I sent email directly to Scandit and they responded *VERY* quickly.  I was shocked and amazed.  There is a README.txt file in the package.  I missed a step, but even after fixing that, it still fails.  Scandit is looking into the issue.  I will post the solution if/when I have one.

Comment: Oh, I should also point out that the corp website "contact us" offers Twitter and email communications.

Comment: I had great response and support from Scandit -- problem was that my license file got altered with extra new-lines in the file.  Probably due to my preview and save-as.  The recommendation was to re-download and copy directly.  That worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points, first of all there was a README.txt file in the ZIP file that answered all of my installation questions and it had a step that I missed.

There was an additional problem that I had with the license file, since I opened it for viewing, the file was altered to have extra  and therefore did not pass the license validation.  The console log stated that the file was invalid.

Scandit looked at the file and determined the problem with the new-lines and as soon as I re-downloaded the file, I was up and running.  Now I can continue with my evaluation.

> w.r.t the license file, there seem to be a couple of additional
>   `newlines` in the file. Can you try downloading the file again from
>   the Scandit website and store it directly (without opening it in an
>   editor) in the ScanditSDK directory? -- scandit support

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you ran into this issue last year.

I work for Scandit, and over the summer we've expanded our website to provide a support section with detailed documentation, FAQs and contact information: http://www.scandit.com/support/documentation/

Please get in touch with any technical questions and we'll get right back to you.

Comment: Thanks!  I hope to start scanning again in 2013 :)